# Given a line and a plane determine whether they are parallel, perpendicular or neither

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, 3d

> The line $L$ passes through the point $p = (1,-1,1)$ and has direction vector $d = [ 2,3, -1]$. Determine for the plane $P$, with equation $2x+3y-z = 1$  whether $L$ is parallel, perpendicular or neither.

So far I know I've been given a line in vector form, so my guess is to compare the normal line from the plane with the line. But I kind of stuck in that part, I don't know how to proceed with this problem, a hint or something is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For $L$ to be parallel to the plane $P$, all you have to do is checking the direction vector $\vec d$ of $L$ is orthogonal to a vector $\vec n$ normal to $P$, i.e. $\vec d \cdot \vec n=0$. You get such a vector from the equation of the plane

For $L$ to be perpendicular to $P$, check $\vec d$ is colinear to $n$, which you can do with the cross-product: $\vec d \times\vec n =\vec 0$.

Comment: thank you, I understand now how to test if the line is parallel, but perpendicular, to the plane we still haven't looked at cross product, is there other way to show that?.

Comment: Yes: you get three non-aligned points in the plane, say $A,B,C$; the direction vector $\vec d$ has to be orthogonal to both $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{AC}$. But in general it will be evident that $\vec n$ and $\vec d$ are collinear: it simply means their coordinates are proportional.